# Inserting JSON into MongoDB converting dates from strings automatically

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object

I have objects that use the keys `updated_at` and `created_at` which have string timestamps like `2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00`. I'm inserting this into MongoDB. The catch is each object can have a variable number of instances of `updated_at` and `created_at` (they are in arrays within). Is there any code out there that can be used to search an array for `updated_at` and `created_at` and replace the values with `$.created_at = new Date($.created_at)`?

```
{
    "name":"thomas",
    "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "logs":[
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
    ]
}
```

to

```
{
    "name":"thomas",
    "created_at":new Date("2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00"),
    "updated_at":new Date("2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00"),
    "logs":[
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":new Date("2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00"),
        },
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":new Date("2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00"),
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// store your data object in x
x = {
    "name":"thomas",
    "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "logs":[
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
    ]
}

// create a traversal function to recurse
function traverse(o) {
    // loop through object
    for (i in o) {
        // if it is a matched key (current regex matches created_at or updated_at)
        // parse the item as a date, and re-store object
        if(i.match(/(cre|upd)ated_at/)){
            o[i] = new Date(o[i])
        }
        // if the key we are looking at is an object, then recurse!
        if (typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            traverse(o[i])
        }
    }
}

// fire it up!
traverse(x)

// check the results
console.dir(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// store your data object in x
x = {
    "name":"thomas",
    "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
    "logs":[
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
        {
            "something":"something",
            "created_at":"2012-08-29T16:04:34-04:00",
        },
    ]
}

// loop through each element of the logs array
for(y in x.logs){
    // modify the `created_at` value of the y-th element
    // by wrapping with the desired string
    x.logs[y].created_at = "new Date(" + x.logs[y].created_at + ")"
}

// check the final format of the object
console.dir(x)
```

Caveat:

The object stores a string containing `new Date ...` ammendment - to store the result of the operation, you would need to adjust the modification line to...

```
x.logs[y].created_at = new Date( x.logs[y].created_at )
```

Comment: This won't get `x.created_at` and `x.updated_at`. This is just a simple example, the real one has many more nested options. I want something that is more search - oriented. Pretend you have an infinitely nested object and you want to replace all of `created_at` and `updated_at`.